# Could someone please explain me the difference between these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, differences

The flight started as soon as I walked through the door.

No sooner had I walked through the door than  the flight started.

Comment: Well, the first one uses correct grammar.

Comment: Hi Chandima, I think your second sentence should be "No sooner had I walked through the door than the flight started." ('than', not 'then'). You might consider editing your question to show this. They basically mean the same thing - that I walked through the door, and then the flight started immediately. The difference is just a matter of style, the second form is more 'literary', and perhaps also more associated with archaic British English

Comment: @ArchContrarian Thank you. I have just edited it. Do you mean that the second form is not used anymore?

Comment: @ArchContrarian identified the only real difference: The second is somewhat more literary/formal. I wouldn't say it's archaic or solely British; I see & hear that structure used here in modern AmE. But it does come off as a bit more flowery. I think it builds in a little bit of suspense. It's the kind of thing you say, for instance, when you're telling a dramatic story about something that happened to you recently. The first sentence, by contrast, is more direct.

Comment: @spoko, yes, I mistyped ... I meant that it's 'slightly' archaic and/or slightly more associated with BrE ... but not exclusively so. And you're right, I've often heard or read this construction used by Americans.

Comment: Are you sure it's _flight_ (what you take to Paris) instead of _fight_ (what happens in bars)?

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, I am sure.

Comment: The sentence does not make sense. FLIGHT is the noun equivalent of "fly", FIGHT is when two or more people hit or argue with each other, either for sport (boxing) or because they are quarrelling over something (e.g. a husband and wife) .

Answer (score 1):

To me, the first sentence states neutrally at what moment the flight started. The second directs attention to the immediacy of the departure, suggesting either "I made it onto the plane with not a moment to spare" (in other words, if I hadn't made it when I did, the plane would have taken off without me) or "Once I got on the plane, the pilot wasted no time in taking off" (in other words, the pilot couldn't leave without me on the plane but was impatient to go and did so the instant I had arrived), depending on the context.